# Fullcalendar :How to change the event title on eventclick

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar

I am using Fullcalender angular 2

```
export class Calender {

        public value: any = 2;
        public modalData: any[];
        calendarOptions: any;
        @ViewChild(CalendarComponent) myCalendar: CalendarComponent;

        changeCalendarView(view) {
            this.myCalendar.fullCalendar('changeView', view);
        }


        form: FormGroup;

        constructor(private route: Router, private calenderservice: CalenderService, private appstate: AppState) {

        }

        ngOnInit() {

            this.calendarOptions = {
                height: '1000',
                fixedWeekCount: false,
                header:
                {
                        left: 'prev,next,today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'month,listYear',
                        },
                defaultDate: '2017-01-01',
                editable: true,
                timeFormat: 'hh:mm A',
                eventLimit: true,



                events: (start, end, title, callback) => {
                   this.calenderservice.getExamCandidateById(this.value)
                       .subscribe(response => {
                           callback(response),
                           this.modalData = response.Items
                           this.myCalendar.fullCalendar('renderEvents', this.modalData)
                           console.log(this.modalData);
                           console.log(response);
                        });
                },

                eventClick: function (event, jsEvent, view) {   
                    alert('Your seat has been reserved on this date and time:' + event.start.format());
                    console.log(event); 
               event.title = "clicked on"; 
                this.myCalendar.fullCalendar('updateEvents', event)
                    localStorage.setItem('Events', JSON.stringify(event));          
                },

               dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
                    alert('Clicked on: ' + date.format());
                }

            };
        }
```

Here on eventclick i am changing the event.title to clicked on, after event showing with new changes in debugger, but calendar not refreshing or updating with new changed events.

please help me,i am newer to angular 2.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the arrow function notation `() => {}`, don't use the `function` keyword, or your `this` context is changed to that function:

```
eventClick: (event, jsEvent, view) => {   
     event.title = "clicked on"; 
     this.myCalendar.fullCalendar('updateEvents', event)
     localStorage.setItem('Events', JSON.stringify(event));          
}
```

Comment: can you please  provide one example for this